# Clip a SpatialGrid using a SpatialPolygon

Tags: r, clip, sp, kriging, subset

In order to perform kriging methods using `automap::autoKrige` I need to provide a `SpatialGrid` for which values can be predicted. I would like to reduce the rectangular grid to the actual area (in this case a lake) for which I want to make the predictions, i.e. clip the `SpatialGrid` with the `SpatialPolygon` of the lake. I stole code from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17962821/how-to-subset-spatialgrid-using-spatialpolygon/22387660#22387660) and [here](https://github.com/filipematias23/cleanRfield#P13).

**Code**

```
easypackages::libraries("tidyverse", "sf", "sp", "osmdata")

get_osm_data <- opq("Starnberger See") %>% 
  add_osm_feature(key = "natural", value = c("water")) %>%
osmdata_sf()
lake_polygon_sf <- get_osm_data[["osm_polygons"]] %>% 
  mutate(area = st_area(geometry)) %>% 
  filter(area == max(area)) %>% 
  st_transform(31468)

lake_polygon_sp <- as_Spatial(lake_polygon_sf)
slot(lake_polygon_sp, "proj4string") <- CRS(SRS_string = "EPSG:31468")

grid <- as.data.frame(spsample(lake_polygon_sp, "regular", n = 10000)) %>% 
  rename(x = x1, y = x2)
coordinates(grid) <- c("x", "y")
gridded(grid) <- TRUE
fullgrid(grid) <- TRUE
slot(grid, "proj4string") <- CRS(SRS_string = "EPSG:31468")

grid_clip <- grid[!is.na(over(grid, lake_polygon_sp)),]
```

**Question**

Unfortunately `grid[!is.na(over(grid, lake_polygon_sp)),]` gives me  `Error in matrix(idx, gr@cells.dim[2], gr@cells.dim[1], byrow = TRUE)[rows, : (subscript) logical subscript too long`. As the polygon was used to create the grid, I don't really see how that can be the case?

N.B.: I have also successfully tried this with `sf::st_intersection`, but as `automap::autoKrige` produces error messages, if I feed it with `sf` objects, I'm specifically looking for a solution for `sp` objects.

Comment: What kind of errors did you encounter with `sf` objects? `autoKrige` should just automate some `gstat` workflows and `gstat` itself should play well with `sf` & `stars`. Noticed no issues when running the first interpolation example of https://r-spatial.org/book/12-Interpolation.html through `automap::autoKrige` .

Comment: @margusl this is what I get using `sf` and `autoKrige`: `Error in h(simpleError(msg, call)) : error in evaluating the argument 'x' in selecting a method for function 'addAttrToGeom': subscript out of bounds`

Comment: What are the argument types / values you are using there? When using points from your previous question, `autoKrige(kg_ha ~ 1, sf::st_as_sf(points), stars::st_as_stars(sf::st_bbox(points), dx = 100))` works fine.  Not sure if the lake in both questions should be the same, but just in case -- https://i.stack.imgur.com/P3AAV.png

Comment: Thanks for linking to my previous question, I probably should have done that in the post. Unfortunately though, running your above code with the data provided in my previous question again produces `Error in h(simpleError(msg, call)) : error in evaluating the argument 'x' in selecting a method for function 'addAttrToGeom': subscript out of bounds`

Comment: I'm not able to reproduce that error - https://gist.github.com/marguslt/152bd2ba594601e4e79218b067639555

Comment: I hate to admit it, but an update of the involved packages solved the problem. Runs fine now, using `sf` objects. Thanks for providing feedback so that I could understand it was not a code related issue.